How to get .env file path?
I have a requirement to fetch the .env file path in nestjs and pass it to the ETLs that are executed from the backend application. my nestjs application is running on a linux machine as a service and the .env file location is passed into NestJS app using
[Unit]
Description=Test Backend
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/test_backend/dev/scripts/start_dev_backend.sh
ExecStartPost=nginx -s reload
Restart=on-failure
WorkingDirectory=/opt/test_backend/dev/backend
EnvironmentFile=/etc/backend/env

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

How can I get this path in a variable in nestjs?
1 option is to have another variable in .env for ETL_CONFIG but it would be ideal if i can dynamically read the .env file path from within nestjs
Update: it's running on linux and this is the backend.service file

is EnvironmentFile an environment variable? or a command line argument? it's unclear from what you've shown

@Bravo I have updated the details of issue and added the service file

wouldn't the environment entries you have in the file /etc/backend/env already be available in process.env?

I think it's unclear to most readers what type of file you are showing. Is this some sort of configuration file of the cloud provider or stack you're using? Could you describe the exact software/stack you are using that is bootstrapping this NestJS application? The answer will most likely heavily depend on it. The goal of an environment file is usually only to load the values within into the environment variables of a running process (in NodeJS it's accessible via process.env) but no guarantees are made that you can backtrack which file these values came from, from inside the process.

I'm guessing this is a systemd unit file, and there's no way to retrieve the environmentfile directive without highly complicated logic to find this file in the filesystem and parsing it. The easiest way would probably be to add an entry in the environment file that contains the path, and update that when you move it, or make a build/deploy step that does so for you. Could you post the contents of /opt/test_backend/dev/scripts/start_dev_backend.sh as well? Could you also explain why you need the path at all?

It turns out that the .env entries that are available in NestJS as process.env are also available in python as os.env
We don't need any additional work to read the variable.s
